# lost my title after passing props.childern

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw0lU.png)After creating a CardSection component and wrapping jsx in my Parent AlbumDetail component to pass props.children I lost my titles.Before adding CardSection the titles were showing up without any issues.

I have tried removing my  jsx tags and am able to then see my album titles. The CardSection code is in the AlbumDetail.js file.

**AlbumDetail.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';
import CardSection from './CardSection';

const AlbumDetail = (props) => {
    return (
        <Card>
         <CardSection>
          <Text>{props.album.title}</Text>
         </CardSection>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default AlbumDetail;
```

**Card.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
             {props.children}
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    containerStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 2,
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.1,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        elevation: 1,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        marginTop: 10
    }
};

export default Card;
```

**CardSection.js**

```
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
           {props.childern}
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = {
    containerStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderColor: '#ddd',
        position: 'relative'
    }
};

export default CardSection;
```

Comment: Typo on `{props.childern}` at **CardSection.js**. Unintentional on copy-pasting code?

Comment: I don't see the typo?

Comment: @zvona, omg I am blind. I see it now, thanks that did the trick. I typed it myself obviously wrong lol

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your AlbumDetail component as

```
const AlbumDetail = (props) => {
    return (
        <Card>
         <CardSection
          albumTitle={props.album.title}>
         />
        </Card>
    );
};
```

and CardSection component as,

```
const CardSection = ({albumTitle}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
           <Text>{albumTitle}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};
```